# Mounting ext3 USB drive in VirtualBox VM under Mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, osx-elcapitan, mount

I have a Mac running OSX El Capitan, which cannot easily mount a Linux ext3 filesystems. I have a USB drive with exactly this file system and need to access.

OSXFUSE + Ext2 FUSE module seems not to work as I have installation errors that might be related to El Capitan being too new (the Ext FUSE module conplains about that at least). There is another commercial product, called Paragon ExtFS, that throws me similar problems for the trail version.

Now, I am thinking of an alternative by using VirtualBox, with an Ubuntu 14.04 that mounts the drive.

I added the following line to /etc/fstab

```
/dev/sdb1       /media/mystuff   ext3    defaults        1       2
```

but rebooting my machine makes no difference. I have to add that this USB drive is USB3.

What am I doing wrong? Can I technically mount a USB drive that Mac per standard does not understand?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/481693

Comment: What does the error message say when you mount it manually ( run:  `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/mystuff`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can mount ext3 in Ubuntu running in VirtualBox on your El Capitan.

That's what worked for me (I had 12.04, but it shouldn't matter):

1. Get the latest VirtualBox and VirtualBox Extension Back from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
2. Make sure your Ubuntu has been shut down, navigate to virtual machine Settings -> Ports -> USB
3. Enable USB Controller, choose USB2.0 just in case as most USB3 devices are backwards compatible. Add your device to the list.
4. Start your Ubuntu, log in and check for devices:
   sudo fdisk -l
5. Make sure you have ext3 as System. It may also be Linux LVM nowadays. If so, proceed with https://superuser.com/a/116634
6. mount manually:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/mystaff
   ```